# Banner Ad not showing outside scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to build an application. I want to show a banner add in the layout such that the banner add is always shown on the screen but the text inside is scroll able.

This is my layout but for some reason the banner ad is not visible. If I shift the banner ad inside the linear layout then the banner ads is visible but I have to scroll it in order to see it. I want it permanently in the bottom at the screen.

I have already seen a couple of examples on stackoverflow and they didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/photoandname"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/displaypic"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Your Name Comes Here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_below="@+id/photoandname"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photoandname"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="Register Number : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/registernumber"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Section : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/section"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Semester : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/year"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Office Name : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/officename"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Course Name : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/coursename"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Father's Name : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fathername"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Date of Birth : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/dob"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sex : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/sex"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Blood Group : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bloodgroup"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Address : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Email : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Student Contact Number : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pincode"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Validity : "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/validity"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/Profile_Banner">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if it works for you

Assuming your activity name is ABCActivity and your package is com.username.appname 
and your xml file name is abc_activity

1. Make a new xml => new_activity
2. Change the content view in the activity

and setContentView(R.layout.new_activity);

3. Content of new_activity

new_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.username.appname.ABCActvity">

    <include layout="@layout/abc_activity" />
<!-- your orignal activity name -->

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/Profile_Banner">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this format:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AdView
    android:id="@+id/yourAdview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ...
    />

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/yourAdview"
    android:layout_below="@id/photoandname">

        <LinearLayout
        ...>

        //scrollview contents here
        ...
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot assign `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`
I already have something above scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Please make scrollview and linear layout (which is inside scrollview)wrap_content instead of match_parent thats why banner ad not getting enough space to show.